# Select file with highest version number in name

Tags: python, glob

The files I need to analyze have multiple versions that are indicated with "run_0x" in the file name, e.g. run_01. The structure of my directory looks like this:

```
subject_01    
  |-- sub01_data_run_01    
  |-- sub01_data_run_02    
subject_02    
  |-- sub02_data_run_02
subject_03
  |-- sub03_data_run_01
```

I would like to loop through the subjects and always select the file with the highest run number, i.e. pick run 2 if it exists but if it doesn't just pick run 1. This is my current solution:

```
import glob
for sub in glob.glob(base_dir + '...'):
    if glob.glob(sub + '*run-02.nii.gz'):
        file = glob.glob(sub + '*run-02.nii.gz')
    elif not glob.glob(sub + '*run-02.nii.gz'):
        file = glob.glob(sub + '*run-01.nii.gz')
```

An additional caveat is that some subjects will just have one file and it won't have run_0x in the name, in that case I'd like to just select this file. I assume I could just sort the contents of the subject folder and select the last file, but I'm afraid that if there is a typo or irregularity in the file name, it will return the wrong one.
I'd appreciate any tips, thank you in advance!

Comment: If you have the directory items in a list of sorts, why not use `sorted(files, key=lambda x: int(x.split('_')[-1]))[-1]`?

Comment: @B Remmelzwaal Thank you for the suggestion! I didn't want to sort the files in case there is an irregularity or typo somewhere, e.g. if one file name is sub01_run_01 and the other is sub_01_2023_run_01. Although it might work fine if I modify your solution so it's x.split('run_')

Comment: I'm pretty sure my solution would cover that, since it's sorting by the last part when splitting on an underscore.